# In what condition does request.getRequestURL() return a URL not from my website?

Tags: http, url, servlets

I am doing a Java-based website. The website gets the URL of each requested page on my site:

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

It saves such URLs in a database table. However, I found a few abnormal entries which are not the URL of a page on my site. For example, if my website's url is like the following:

```
http://www.example.com/abc
```

The abnormal entries look like these:

```
http://www.thedresden.org/
http://www.camptuckerman.org/
```

Let's not talk about where these abnormal URLs are from. I would like know how `request.getRequestURL()` returns the URL of other sites. What I learned in the past is that `request.getRequestURL()` returns the URL of the requested page on my site. Do I miss something?

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is an [http](/questions/tagged/http) matter more than it is a [java](/questions/tagged/java) one.

When a browser connects to a website it tells the webserver what site (hostname) it is looking for. This is how 1 webserver can handle content for multiple different sites at the same time ("virtual hosts")

E.g. The Example Company might have a US website at `example.com` and a British site at `example.co.uk`. They can be hosted by the same webserver, but show different content.

The way this works is that the browsers includes a "Host" header when it makes an HTTP request. That way the webserver knows which content to return to the client. So, for example, when I load `stackoverflow.com`, my browser includes a header of

```
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

You can see that header if you look in the "net" tab in the developer tools of your browser (exact details vary between browsers).

Nothing in this process technically requires that the client side (browser) be *honest* with the webserver.

So, I can do this:

```
curl 'http://stackoverflow.com' -H 'Host: example.com'
```

Which requests a page from the webserver at "stackoverflow.com" but tells the webserver that I want content for "example.com".
In this case, because stackoverflow.com is served up by cloudflare, I get a cloudflare error page.

It would appear that for some reason some "browsers" (or quite possibly bots) are accessing your webserver and asking for pages on other domains (like `www.camptuckerman.org`).
`HttpServletRequest.getRequestUrl()` reconstructs the URL that the browser asked for by looking at the underlying HTTP request content, including the `Host` header.
If the browser sent an incorrect host, then that's what you'll see in `getRequestUrl`.

Comment: Tim, thanks so much for your answer. I typed `http://www.example.com -H http://www.abcdefg.com` in Chrome and Firefox, my website did not get called and I did not see any website request from outside. Are you saying bots, curl or some other tools are able to construct 'bad' headers and so my website produces abnormal URLs?

Comment: I also tried curl `http://example.com' -H 'Host: example.com` on Windows (certainly replaced `example` with the actual domain name). My website did not get any web request. How can I test out what you said on Windows? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a regular windows user, so I can't help you there. I believe the LiveHttpHeaders plugin for Firefox allows you to replay requests with altered headers, so that might be an option.

Comment: I will give it try. Thanks so much for your info!

Answer (score -2):

I think URL forwarding is taking place in your servlet with your requests so request.getRequestURL() is returning other sites.

Comment: alim, thanks for your input. I have hard time to understand how it happens as you explained. Could you please show a few steps that I can use to program to test it out?